# List comprehension instead of using append in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I want to use list comprehension instead of using append method because it make the code runs faster however when it is a numpy array it doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2 , 4])
b = np.array([6, 5 , 2])
A = []
B = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    if a[i] > value1 and b[i] > value1:
        A.append(a[i])
        B.append(b[i])
```

for example I am trying something like this:

```
A = [a[i] for i in range(1, 3) if a[i] > value1 and b[i] > value1]
```

and finally is there a way to define a general function that append elements from an array of numbers in a new list based on if conditions like the mentioned example.

Comment: Was this tagged [tag:python-2.7] by mistake?

Comment: This iterative example will be faster if `a` and `b` were lists instead of arrays.  The list comprehension will be modestly faster than the append loop, but not if you need 2 comprehensions to also create `B`. But for arrays, try to avoid either loop.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays don't have an append method. You also shouldn't use `for` loops with numpy arrays because that's slow. Instead, use vectorized operations and make use of broadcasting.

```py
cond = (a > value1) & (b > value1)
A = a[cond]
B = b[cond]
```

Comment: Can it be modified to include more than one condition like:
A = a[cond1 and cond2]

Comment: Almost, you have to use `&` to do the bitwise operation. Also, I added the parentheses I forgot. It won't work without them (because of operator precedence).

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a function to do the above operation. (i.e) if the element is greater than specific value, that should be returned as an array.

```
import numpy as np
def append(array1, array2, value1):
    A = [array1[i] for i in range(len(array1)) if array1[i] > value1 and array2[i] > value1]
    B = [array2[i] for i in range(len(array1)) if array1[i] > value1 and array2[i] > value1]
    return [A,B]

a=np.array([1, 2 , 4,3,4,7,8])
b=np.array([6, 5 , 2,5,7,8,9])

r= append(a,b,2)
A = r[0]
B = r[1] 
print(A)
print(B)

#output:
[3, 4, 7, 8]
[5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Notice that the original code has both `a` and `b` greater than `value1`, not individually.

Comment: With 2  list  comprehensions, this probably isn't any faster than the original `append` loop.  Each comprehension requires an iteration through the arrays.

Comment: Python oneliner are not faster than the append method. Though numpy is imported, I didn't use it because you were bothered about the speed. The purpose of  me not using numpy is : lesser the modules imported,, lesser the time taken to execute. If you think in that sense, this should be the faster comparing tho other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean condition is created using (array1 > value1) & (array2 > value1), and this condition is directly used for boolean indexing to select elements from array1 and array2. This avoids the need for explicit appending

```
import numpy as np

def filter_arrays(array1, array2, value1):
    condition = (array1 > value1) & (array2 > value1)
    return array1[condition], array2[condition]

value1 = 2
a=np.array([1,2,4,3,4,7,8])
b=np.array([6,5,2,5,7,8,9])
A, B = filter_arrays(a, b, 2)
print(A)
print(B)
[3 4 7 8]
[5 7 8 9]
```

or simply

```
a=np.array([1, 2 , 4,3,4,7,8])
b=np.array([6, 5 , 2,5,7,8,9])
value1 = 2  # You need to define the value1 variable

mask = (a > value1) & (b > value1)
A = a[mask]
B = b[mask]

print(A)
print(B)
```

Comment: Notice that the original code has both `a` and `b` greater than `value1`, not individually.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**